# Initialize member array of user defined objects in the constructor in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

How do I initialize member array in my constructor? The member array is an array of user-defined objects(classes).
Also, the number of elements in the array could be large more than 100, so I do not prefer to use initializer-list available in C++11 (unless there's some better way)

For instance, refer following code:

```
class Foo {
private:
   void *a;
   int b;
public:   
   Foo(void *, int);
   ~Foo();
}

class Bar {
private:
    Foo mObj[150];
public:
    Bar();
    ~Bar();
};

Bar::Bar() {
// ???
}
```

For sake of simplicity, assume I would like to initialize the members as follows: let's say member int b stores Sr. no & void *a store null ptr as of now... so mObj[0] = {0, nullptr}, mobj[1] = {1, nullptr} & so on..

1. What should my Bar::Bar() constructor be like?
2. Do I need to have Default const, Copy const & operator= for Foo()?
3. Having Vector instead of an array a better option?

Comment: "Having Vector instead of an array a better option?" -- Yes!!

Comment: Initialize to **what**?

Comment: @FredLarson not necessarily. Not enough information is given to jump to this conclusion.

Comment: @SergeyA Initialize with valid values. For instance, let's say member int b stores Sr. no & void *a store null ptr as of now... so mObj[0] = {0, nullptr}, mobj[1] = {1, nullptr} & so on..

Comment: @SergeyA: I think vector (or std::array, or other container) should always be preferred over old-fashioned array unless there is a compelling argument otherwise.

Comment: @RamBo: 150 items is a pretty big initialization list, but you can do it.

Comment: @FredLarson I would agree with this statement (vector **or array**). Your original statement implied that `vector` is preferred, and this is what I disagreed with.

Comment: @RamBo you can do this with meta-programming. Will post answer.

Comment: If the number of objects is known at `compile-time` and isn't relatively large (able to fit in the `stackframe` and is `cache-friendly`), then `template` this `class` and use `std::array`, if the number of objects is not known at `compile-time` and can only be determined at `runtime` or exceeds the size of the `stackframe` and has potential to have many `cache` misses then use `std::vector`. That's my suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it seems like the ultimate task at hand is to call `Foo` constructor for each element of the array with arguments of `(i, nullptr)`, where `i` is increased on each iteration from 0 to N.

Here is the code which would do this with `std::index_sequence`. This was only introduced with C++14, so if you are not using it, you will have to do implement it yourself, which is not hard at all - let me know if you need help with that.

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>

struct Foo {
    Foo(void*, int);
};

class Bar {
private:
    static constexpr size_t array_sz = 150;
    template<size_t... Ix> Bar(std::index_sequence<Ix...> ) :
        mObj{Foo{nullptr, Ix}...}     { }
    std::array<Foo, array_sz> mObj;
public:
    Bar();
    ~Bar();
};

Bar::Bar() : Bar(std::make_index_sequence<array_sz>{}) { }
```

Comment: Note that OP tagged the question C++11, while `std::index_sequence` was introduced in C++14.

Comment: @eerorika this is a good point. It is quite easy to hand-rollindex_sequence in C++11, I will edit the answer.